# getsockopt: connection refused when running a bootnode

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

- Geth version: v1.6.0-unstable-1018bf6a/linux/go1.7.3
- OS & Version: Linux/Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (x86_64)

I want to set up a private distributed blockchain network. I am failing to make nodes (running on different machines) recognize each other.

Both nodes have the same genesis file and are connected to the same networkId.

```
INFO Successfully wrote genesis state  hash=X (hash equal on both nodes)
```

The UDP Port 30301 of the bootnode is open

```
> netcat -u -z -v <PUB-IP> 30301
Connection to <PUB-IP> 30301 port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

When I start the bootnote I pass the following arguments:

```
--nodekey <FILE> —addr :30301 --nat extip:<PUB-IP> --verbosity 9
```

The logs confirm that it is successfully created and listening:

```
INFO Mapped network port    proto=udp extport=30301 intport=30301 interface=ExtIP(<PUB-IP>)
DEBUG UDP listener up       self=enode://<PUB-ID>@<PUB-IP>:30301
```

When I start the node I pass the following arguments:

```
--cache=512 --verbosity=6 --datadir <DIR> --nat extip:<PUB-IP> --networkid=<VAL*> --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi=eth,net,web3,personal,db --rpccorsdomain '*' --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --bootnodes enode://<PUB-ID>@<PUB-IP>:30301 --identity node1
```

*(I am using a big networkId but it is inside the BigInteger range)

The logs on the node confirm that the bootnode is well identified

```
INFO  Starting P2P networking 
# >> Info about the current node:
DEBUG UDP listener up             self=enode://<PUB-ID>@<PUB-IP>:30303
INFO  Mapped network port         proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface=ExtIP(<PUB-IP>)
# >> Info about the bootnode:
TRACE Starting bonding ping/pong  id=<PUB-ID-SHORT> known=false failcount=0 age=XmXs
```

But connection fails and `admin.peers` shows no peers

```
TRACE >> PING/v4                 addr=<PUB-IP>:30301 err=nil
TRACE Starting bonding ping/pong id=<PUB-ID-SHORT> known=false failcount=0 age=XmXs
TRACE >> PING/v4                 addr=<PUB-IP>:30301  err=nil
```

When I try adding the bootnode manually, `admin.addPeer("enode://..")` returns true but the logs show:

```
DEBUG Adding static node    node=enode://<PUB-ID>@<PUB-IP>:30301
TRACE New dial task         task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301"
TRACE Dial error            task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301" err="dial tcp <PUB-IP>:30301: getsockopt: connection refused"
DEBUG Resolving node failed id=<PUB-ID-SHORT> newdelay=2m0s
TRACE Dial task done        task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301"
TRACE New dial task         task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301"
TRACE Dial error            task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301" err="dial tcp <PUB-IP>:30301: getsockopt: connection refused"
TRACE Dial task done        task="staticdial <PUB-ID-SHORT> <PUB-IP>:30301"
```

I have tried as well to connect via `static-nodes.json`, where I indicate the bootnode's address in all nodes; and also without the `--bootnodes` flag, where somehow my nodes are not being recognized either, yet there are some [random external nodes that are displayed as peers sporadically](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/private-network-handshaking-with-external-pools/13405#13405). I have tried specifying `--maxpeers` ([following BokkyPooBah's advice](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2734/6320)) as well and seems to make no difference.

Please, help me.

Comment: One idea would be to leave both UDP and TCP on the default ports of `30303`, and not change the listening (UDP) port to `30301`. (It _looks_ like one of your nodes has UDP `30303` and the other UDP `30301`, which might not matter as you've specified the ports in the passed-in options. Personally I'd have everything as port `30303`... )

Comment: I could try switching the bootnode port to 30303. In the network I am building the nodes use UDP 30303 but the bootnode uses 30301. The console display where port UDP 30303 is enabled corresponds to the regular node.

Comment: Well, with port 30303 on the bootnode, it does seem to have more activity but it is still not getting the other node that explicitly connects to it. I guess the reason why 30301 would be better for bootnode and node is to have less traffic. But why don't they recognize each other?

Comment: Have you checked if all servers are with the same datetime?
Best, Marcello Kazuo

Comment: yes I have. They have been syncronized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked. I still don't really know what did it but I will list here some of the changes that got it to work. When I figure out what exactly did it I will update my answer.

- Use the `--v5disc` flag for node discovery.
- The bootnode took ages to start with the `--v5` flag so instead of using a bootnode I chose a random node as bootnode. I started my node with the `--bootnodes` referring to this regular node but didn't seem to work until I manually added it. Probably using `static-nodes.json` would have worked as well.
- **Use a small networkId**. I think I was too optimistic on the size of this value. Once I ran geth and realized that it was using a different NetworkID from the one I entered. This was not a good sign but instead of choosing a smaller value I chose as the value that geth was suggesting. I only realized there was something wrong going on when I got this error `Protocol eth/63 failed   id=X conn=inbound err="NetworkId mismatch - 3853220132 (!= 1245324517197969700)"`. I am now using a 10-digit networkId and this is what seems to have done the trick.
- [Possibly not necessary] Run a node in miner mode (`personal.newAccount("pw")`, `miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])` & `miner.start()`)

I am more inclined to think it was the networkId that was causing some sort of problem. At least switching to `v5` made it more easy to detect.