# Why is my private ethereum network stuck at "Recalculated downloader QoS values" while trying to mine?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

I'm using Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.6

My customgenesis.json file is this.

```
{"config": {
"chainId": 15,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0 },"nonce": "0x0000000000000042","timestamp": "0x00","parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","extraData": "0x00","gasLimit": "0x08000000","difficulty": "0x0400", "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","coinbase": "0xd77821c8b92e3e29bc63c8f2a94a6c6a64b28b53", "alloc": {
"0xd08658a4e33bf6ca786b9870d91ec51a0dc72e56": {"balance": "10000"} }}
```

After creating the customgenesis.json, I ran the following command

```
geth --datadir ./mychaindata init ./customgenesis.json
```

This created my blockchain directory.
After this I ran the following command to start the private network.

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./mychaindata --nodiscover --verbosity 4 --unlock 0
```

I even tried the following command to start the private network. And tried with and without --nodiscover flags.

```
geth --datadir=.\mychaindata\. --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --unlock 0 --mine
```

Once I attach to the pic file using a different console, and start mining using the command `miner.start()`

[image: This is the debug window once I start the mining process]

I also tried specifying 100 threads using `miner.start(100)`. Ended up getting the same results.

I thought maybe the difficulty was set high and hence my CPU could not mine. So I ran `etc.getBlock("latest").[image: This was the latest block and difficulty is set to 1024]

Any help or input is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/13756/46798. What returns eth.mining and eth.syncing in the geth console ?  The problem you might face is that the mining is too slow, because your hardware isn't just powerful enough. I had actually similar problem, because I used a VM (1vCPU, 2GB RAM) for mining, which is apparently not enough.